# Javascript Decimal Subtract

Tags: javascript

I am trying this code on the Firefox console, and I don't know how to get the correct answer(0.11). I would like to understand why this code doesn't work as I expected. Can someone help me understand. Thanks!

```
  var a = "12,25";
  var b = "12,14";

  console.log("A: " + a);
  console.log("B: " + b);

  var parsedA = parseFloat(a.replace(',', '.'));
  var parsedB = parseFloat(b.replace(',', '.'));

  console.log('Parsed A: ' + parsedA);
  console.log('Parsed B: ' + parsedB);

  console.log("Dif Parsed Float: " + (parsedA - parsedB));

  var numberA = Number(a.replace(',', '.'));
  var numberB = Number(b.replace(',', '.'));

  console.log('Number A: ' + numberA);
  console.log('Number B: ' + numberB);

  console.log("Dif Number: " + (parsedA - parsedB));
```

Comment: Just do `(parsedA - parsedB).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Yes, it's that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use toFixed(2) for your result

```
  var a = "12,25";
  var b = "12,14";

  console.log("A: " + a);
  console.log("B: " + b);

  var parsedA = parseFloat(a.replace(',', '.'));
  var parsedB = parseFloat(b.replace(',', '.'));

  console.log('Parsed A: ' + parsedA);
  console.log('Parsed B: ' + parsedB);

  console.log("Dif Parsed Float: " + (parsedA - parsedB));

  var numberA = Number(a.replace(',', '.'));
  var numberB = Number(b.replace(',', '.'));

  console.log('Number A: ' + numberA);
  console.log('Number B: ' + numberB);

  console.log("Dif Number: " + (parsedA - parsedB).toFixed(2)); //<<< here
```